# Typescript redux connected component type error

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I am trying to merge state from redux into properties in a react component defined in a tsx file.

I have defined the type LoggedInUserState elsewhere, it is exported like this in its file:

```
import { Action, Reducer } from 'redux';

// -----------------
// STATE - This defines the type of data maintained in the Redux store.

export interface LoggedInUserState {
    userName: string,
    isAdmin: boolean,
    isUserManager: boolean
}
```

This is my tsx file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { LoggedInUserState } from 'ClientApp/store/LoggedInUser';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';


export interface LinkProps {
    routeTo: string,
    name: string,
    glyphIcon: string
}

interface LoginStateProps {
    isAuthenticated: boolean
}

type ExpandedAuthProps =
    LinkProps & LoginStateProps;

class AuthenticatedLink extends React.Component<ExpandedAuthProps, null> {

    public render() {
        return this.props.isAuthenticated ?
            <NavLink exact to={this.props.routeTo} activeClassName='active'>
                <span className={this.props.glyphIcon}></span> {this.props.name}
            </NavLink> : 
            <NavLink exact to={'/loginUser'} activeClassName='active'>
                <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle'></span> {this.props.name}
            </NavLink>;
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: LoggedInUserState, originalProps: LinkProps): ExpandedAuthProps {
    return {
        routeTo: originalProps.routeTo,
        name: originalProps.name,
        glyphIcon: originalProps.glyphIcon,
        isAuthenticated: state.userName != ''
    }
}

export default connect<LoggedInUserState, {}, LinkProps>
    (mapStateToProps)(AuthenticatedLink) as typeof AuthenticatedLink;
```

TypeScript shows the following type error on the final line (mapStateToProps) of my tsx file:

> Argument of type '(state: LoggedInUserState, originalProps: LinkProps)
>   => ExpandedAuthProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam'.   Type '(state:
>   LoggedInUserState, originalProps: LinkProps) => ExpandedAuthProps' is
>   not assignable to type 'MapStateToPropsFactory'.
>       Types of parameters 'originalProps' and 'ownProps' are incompatible.
>         Type 'LinkProps | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LinkProps'.
>           Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'LinkProps'.

What is wrong with the declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error you got; I get a different one.  This compiles for me:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthenticatedLink);
```

If I understand react-redux correctly, you shouldn't be asserting the result back to `typeof AuthenticatedLink`.  The whole point of the `connect` is that it changes the props type of the component from `ExpandedAuthProps` to `LinkProps` because the `LoginStateProps` part is supplied by your `mapStateToProps` function.